# Node/Express - How to change default root URL

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes

I have a single page application I am working on. The goal is to have the main root route be something other than www.website.com. Something like www.website.com/cool-page This is for SEO purposes. I am not sure if it is best practice or even possible.

Thus far I've been able to change the URL on load using this:

```
// root route
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/cool-page');
});
```

This gives me an error that the page redirected you too many times.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your routing definition looks like it would redirect every request to URLs within the root URL, not just those going to the root URL itself. So it will redirect even the redirected requests going to `/cool-page`, forming an infinite loop. Try using `router.get('/', ... )` instead, I think that would redirect only requests made to the root url,